# jQuery disable when checkbox is checked when page is loaded (not only on click or change)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input fields by id `Location` (select) and `isOnline` (checkbox). When the checkbox `isOnline` is checked after clicked on, the field `Location` gets disabled. The only issue I have is when the checkbox `isOnline` is already checked when loading a page, the field `Location` is not disabled, because the JavaScript requires a click. 
**Question:**
How to disable a form field on load when a checkbox is checked?

**HTML**

```
<label>Location </label>
<select id="location">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
</select>
<strong>or:</strong>
<input type="checkbox" id="isOnline" checked="checked" />
<label>no location </label>
```

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

 $("#isOnline").click(function() {
   if (jQuery(this).prop("checked")) {
     jQuery("#location")
       .prop("disabled", this)
       .attr("placeholder", '')
       .val(null);
   } else {
     jQuery("#location")
       .prop("disabled", false)
       .attr("placeholder", 'the name of the city')
       .val(null);
   }
 });
});
```

**Example**: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nj5xscke/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added an if statement in the `jQuery(document).ready()` function that checks if `isOnline` is checked and disables the form.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  $('#isOnline').click(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).prop('checked')) {
      jQuery('#location')
        .prop('disabled', this)
        .attr('placeholder', '')
        .val(null);
    } else {
      jQuery('#location')
        .prop('disabled', false)
        .attr('placeholder', 'Enter the name of the city')
        .val(null);
    }
  });

  if ($('#isOnline').is(':checked')) {
    jQuery('#location')
      .prop('disabled', this)
      .attr('placeholder', '')
      .val(null);

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Location </label>
<select id="location">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

<br>

<strong>or:</strong>
<input type="checkbox" id="isOnline" checked="checked" />
<label>no location </label>
```

Also, a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v1kqzdgm/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create methods as follows.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#isOnline").prop("checked")) {
    disableLocation();
  }
  $("#isOnline").click(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
      disableLocation();
    } else {
      enableLocation();
    }
  });
});
function disableLocation() {
  $("#location")
    .prop("disabled", true)
    .attr("placeholder", '')
    .val(null);
}
function enableLocation() {
  $("#location")
    .prop("disabled", false)
    .attr("placeholder", 'the name of the city')
    .val(null);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Location </label>
<select id="location">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
</select>
<strong>or:</strong>
<input type="checkbox" id="isOnline" checked="checked" />
<label>no location </label>
```